# Access Keychain in the background

Tags: swift, ios11, keychain

I am unable to access my password from keychain in the background when I have passcode/touch-id access control set up.

---

### Details

My SecItem has the kSecAttrAccessible set to kSecAttrAccessibleAlways for debugging purposes, and I am accessing my password with SecItemCopyMatching.

```
Sample configuration for kSecAttrAccessControl
SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,
    .userPresence,
    nil)
```

Everything works fine when I attempt to access the key in the background/foreground.

Once I enforce a passcode/touch-id to access the password then I am prompted with the passcode screen when I am in the foreground. However; if I attempt to do the same thing from the background then I receive error code -25308 and error text saying "User Interaction is required".

I want the passcode/touch-id screen to pop up when the application is in the background so I can grab the password from keychain to perform a background task.

Can keychain access with passcode/touch-id be done from the background?

### Additional Information

- I am cleaning my keychain, and creating new items with the different access control.
- I have background mode on in my capabilities, and it is added in Info.plist.
- This application is able to trigger the passcode from the lockscreen, so I am sure that it is possible, it may not be accessing keychain though -- https://help.duo.com/s/article/3142?language=en_US.

Comment: Add 'Required background modes' in the plist.

Comment: This is already done.

I am able to grab the password from keychain in the background when I do not have the passcode/touch-id enforcement.